# Elegant Way to Check toInt or toBoolean

Tags: scala

I have a bunch of fields that I am parsing in XML and they need to be converted to `Int` or `Boolean` Type depending on the field. The problem is that in some cases of the XML file this tag may not exist. This naturally throws a runtime error when I try to convert an empty `String` to `Boolean` or `Int`. I am new to Scala, is there a way to use the `Option` class to do this better?

This is what the code without handling looks like. The parentNode always exists but the child node or field may not.

```
(parentNode / childNote / field).text.toBoolean
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `scala.util.Try` for that. If the code inside the `Try`-block is successful it will yield a `Success(result)`. Otherwise a `Failure(exception)` is returned.

```
Try((parentNode / childNote / field).text.toBoolean)
```

From here you have several options to deal with it. I assume that, in the case where the field does not exist you have a default value.

1 If the failure is not important, you can directly use `getOrElse` and in a failure case the default value will be used.

```
Try((parentNode / childNote / field).text.toBoolean).getOrElse(defaultvalue)
```

2 Pattern-Matching

This should only be used, when you have several methods calls and/or exception handling.

```
Try((parentNode / childNote / field).text.toBoolean) match {
  case Success(bool) => {
    //calculations
  }
  case Failure(ex) => {
    //do something with the exception
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I would do it the same way. If you're unfamiliar with how Try differs from "try," check out the chapter "Handling Errors without Exceptions" from the upcoming book "Functional Programming in Scala" by Paul Chiusano and Runar Bjarnason (Manning Press). It's almost in print and you can get the PDF from manning.com. They discuss these exception-free patterns at length. Otherwise, for basic infromation, look here: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html

Comment: If I am doing this repeatedly would you recommend isolating it out to a function?\

Comment: If it increases readability and you have a reusable pattern. Why not?